# Given 2d dimensions and values for each items. Find maximum value you can get by filling in items in n x n container

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

This sounds very similar to knapsack or bin packing problem but I do not know how to approach it. The items are given 2d dimensions (width and height) instead of weights.

```
Ex. 
container: 10 x 10

items: [
    w: 3, h: 5, value: 160,
    w: 5, h: 5, value: 250,
    w: 2, h: 5, value: 150,
    w: 2, h: 3, value: 10,
]

constraints:
- items are rectangles (not necessarily squares)
- can use same items more than once
- n <= 20
```

Tried solving it using greedy approach, filling up the container with highest value per square area first. However, this doesn't always result in max profit.

Comment: If you want an optimal solution, you might have to brute force it

Comment: @F43nd1r Obviously this is not the case. Mathematical optimization provides lots of models and tools to do way better than complete enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be formulated as a Mixed-Integer Programming (MIP) problem.

I tried this out: I assumed integer lengths and widths. Basically, use as decision variables:

```
 x(k,i,j) = 1 if item k is placed at cell (i,j)
            0 otherwise
```

I used the convention that "placing at (i,j)" is about the left-upper corner of the item (see the display below). Then for each cell (i',j') we require that only one item can cover it. That is a bit of a complex constraint:

```
 sum((i,j)|covered(k,i,j,i',j'), x(k,i,j)) <= 1   for all (i',j')
```

where `covered(k,i,j,i',j')` indicates if cell (i',j') is covered by item k if it is placed at cell (i,j).

Then the objective is

```
  max sum((k,i,j)|ok(k,i,j), x(k,i,j)*value(k))
```

here `ok(k,i,j)` indicates if item k can be placed at cell (i,j).

I tried this with your example. The results are:

```
----     74 VARIABLE x.L  item k is placed at (i,j)

            r1.c1       r1.c3       r1.c5       r1.c7       r4.c1       r6.c3       r6.c5       r6.c7

item3                       1           1           1           1
item4           1                                                           1           1           1


----     74 VARIABLE totalValue.L          =      640.000  objective (maximized)

----     79 PARAMETER occupy  items occupy cells

            c1          c2          c3          c4          c5          c6          c7          c8

r1           4           4           3           3           3           3           3           3
r2           4           4           3           3           3           3           3           3
r3           4           4           3           3           3           3           3           3
r4           3           3           3           3           3           3           3           3
r5           3           3           3           3           3           3           3           3
r6           3           3           4           4           4           4           4           4
r7           3           3           4           4           4           4           4           4
r8           3           3           4           4           4           4           4           4
```

Obviously, this is not completely trivial.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with integer programming. I'll definitely look into it. do you have any recommendation on where to start? otherwise, I'll just google things up. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: There is a ton of information out there.